# How to pick alternate machines for each datacenters?

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary

Given List of datacenters which are phx, slc, lvs and list of machines, h0, h1, h2, h3 as mentioned below -

```
Datacenters = phx, slc, lvs
Machines = h0, h1, h2, h3
```

I want to generate below combinations only -

```
a)   phx - h0
     slc - h1
     lvs - h2

b)   phx - h1
     slc - h2
     lvs - h3

c)   phx - h2
     slc - h3
     lvs - h0

d)   phx - h3
     slc - h0
     lvs - h1
```

I need to call `getDatacenterMachineMapping` method which will give me above results. For the first call, it should give me above `a result` in the `coloHost` map, in the second call, it should give me above `b result` in the `coloHost` map, in the third call, it should give me above `c result` in the `coloHost` map and for the fourth call, it should give me above `d result` in the `coloHost` map and the fifth call, it should not give me anything as no combination is left.

```
private static List<String> colo = Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "lvs");
private static List<String> hosts = Arrays.asList("h0","h1","h2", "h3");

while(true) {
    Map<String, String> coloHost = getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    System.out.println(coloHost);
}

private static Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {

// some code here?

}
```

Each datacenter in the each pass should get alternate machines/hosts. They should not get same machines. For example in `a` as shown above - `phx gets h0`, `slc gets h1`, `lvs gets h2` so all the machines are different for each datacenters. And in the second pass as shown in `b` - now `phx gets h1` (becuase phx already got h0 in the first pass), `slc got h2` (bcoz slc already got h1 in the first pass), and `lvs got h3`(bcoz lvs already got h2 in the first pass) and etc etc.

And one more example -  if I have only three hosts, then below combination I am supposed to get only -

```
Datacenters = phx, slc, lvs
Machines = h0, h1, h2

a)   phx - h0
     slc - h1
     lvs - h2

b)   phx - h1
     slc - h2
     lvs - h0

c)   phx - h2
     slc - h0
     lvs - h1
```

Any thoughts how this can be done?

**Update:-**

I tried your below code and it works fine. I am using infinite while loop in my main method so which means, it will keep on calling `getDatacenterMachineMapping` method always. So here is the output I am getting which is looking good.

```
{phx=h0, slc=h1, vs=h2}
{phx=h1, slc=h2, vs=h3}
{phx=h2, slc=h3, vs=h0}
{phx=h3, slc=h0, vs=h1}

{phx=h0, slc=h1, vs=h2}
{phx=h1, slc=h2, vs=h3}
{phx=h2, slc=h3, vs=h0}
```

So if you take a look into above mapping that got printed out.. First four is the only result I am expecting and after that I don't want `getDatacenterMachineMapping` to give any result since by that time, all the four machines for phx got printed out, all four machines for slc got printed out and all four machines for vs got printed out. And if you see the fifth row, it is starting again which I don't want `getDatacenterMachineMapping` to give the result.

Below is my code which I have tried -

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs"),
                Arrays.asList("h0", "h1", "h2", "h3"));

        while(true) {
            Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
            System.out.println(m1);
        }
    }

    class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private boolean firstCall = true;
    private int hostListIndex = 0;
    private List<String> datacenterList, hostList;

    public DatacenterMachineMapping(List<String> datacenterList, List<String> hostList) {
        this.datacenterList = datacenterList;
        this.hostList = hostList;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {
        Map<String, String> datacenterMachineMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if(! firstCall) {
            if(hostListIndex == 0) {
                hostListIndex = hostList.size();
            }
            hostListIndex--;
        } else {
            firstCall = false;
        }
        for(String datacenter : datacenterList) {
            if(hostListIndex == hostList.size()) {
                hostListIndex = 0;
            }
            datacenterMachineMapping.put(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex++));
        }
        hostListIndex--;
        return datacenterMachineMapping;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern I could see from host indexing is that each subsequent call to `getDatacenterMachineMapping` starts at the index `i-1` where `i` is the index of the last host from the previous call. The first call start at index `0` and is rotating aroud the available hosts.

For example, with the first host list: `h0, h1, h2, h3`

you have

```
1) 0=h0, 1=h1, 2=h2
```

last index is `2`, subtract 1 from it -> `1` and this is the index where next call should start at:

```
2) 1=h1, 2=h2, 3=h3
```

Now the last index is 3, i.e you start the next call at `2` which leave you only two host in the list, you have then to rotate, i.e. go back to index `0` again, this gives you

```
3) 2=h2, 3=h3, 0=h0
```

The same applies to the second host list.

Here a sample implementation of the above (may need to be adapted to exactly match your requirements, for example to check whether or not a data center has already got any possible host, you may wrap it into an own class along with set (HashSet) of already assigned hosts):

```
public class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private boolean firstCall = true;
    private int hostListIndex = 0;
    private List<String> datacenterList, hostList;

    public DatacenterMachineMapping(List<String> datacenterList, List<String> hostList) {
        this.datacenterList = datacenterList;
        this.hostList = hostList;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {
        Map<String, String> datacenterMachineMapping = new HashMap<>();
        if(! firstCall) {
            if(hostListIndex == 0) {
                hostListIndex = hostList.size();
            }
            hostListIndex--;
        } else {
            firstCall = false;
        }
        for(String datacenter : datacenterList) {
            if(hostListIndex == hostList.size()) {
                hostListIndex = 0;
            }
            datacenterMachineMapping.put(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex++));
        }
        hostListIndex--;
        return datacenterMachineMapping;
    }
}
```

And some testings...

```
public class DatacenterMachineMappingTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs"),
                Arrays.asList("h0", "h1", "h2", "h3"));

        Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m1.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m1.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m2 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m2.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m2.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m2.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m3 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m3.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m3.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m3.get("vs"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs"),
                Arrays.asList("h0", "h1", "h2"));

        Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m1.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m1.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m2 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m2.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m2.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m2.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m3 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m3.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m3.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m3.get("vs"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs"),
                Arrays.asList("h0", "h1"));

        Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m1.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m2 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m2.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m2.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m2.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m3 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m3.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m3.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m3.get("vs"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test4() {
        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs"),
                Arrays.asList("h0", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"));

        Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m1.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m1.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m2 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m2.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m2.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m2.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m3 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m3.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m3.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m3.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m4 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m4.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m4.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m4.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m5 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m5.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m5.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m5.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m6 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m6.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m6.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m6.get("vs"));

        Map<String, String> m7 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m7.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m7.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m7.get("vs"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test5() {
        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs", "sls"),
                Arrays.asList("h0", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"));

        Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m1.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m1.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m1.get("sls"));

        Map<String, String> m2 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m2.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m2.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m2.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m2.get("sls"));

        Map<String, String> m3 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m3.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m3.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m3.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m3.get("sls"));

        Map<String, String> m4 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m4.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m4.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m4.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m4.get("sls"));

        Map<String, String> m5 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m5.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h2", m5.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m5.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m5.get("sls"));

        Map<String, String> m6 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h3", m6.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h4", m6.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m6.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m6.get("sls"));

        Map<String, String> m7 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
        Assert.assertEquals("h5", m7.get("phx"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h6", m7.get("slc"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h0", m7.get("vs"));
        Assert.assertEquals("h1", m7.get("sls"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Add a map for mapping each data center an the host it already has received:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> dataCenterHostsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now add a condition for adding a host to a data center: a host may only be added if it has not already been added:

```
if(addDataCenterHost(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex))) {
    datacenterMachineMapping.put(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex++));    
}
```

The method `addDataCenterHost` looks like this:

```
private boolean addDataCenterHost(String datacenter, String host) {
    Set<String> dataCenterHostSet = dataCenterHostsMap.get(datacenter);
    if(dataCenterHostSet == null) {
        dataCenterHostSet = new HashSet<String>();
        dataCenterHostsMap.put(datacenter, dataCenterHostSet);
    }
    return dataCenterHostSet.add(host);
}
```

With this change `test3` will no longer run successfully, I guess you know why ;-) .

Here is a changed `test1` which test for the 5th call.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
            Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "vs"),
            Arrays.asList("h0", "h1", "h2", "h3"));

    Map<String, String> m1 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    Assert.assertEquals("h0", m1.get("phx"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h1", m1.get("slc"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h2", m1.get("vs"));

    Map<String, String> m2 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    Assert.assertEquals("h1", m2.get("phx"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h2", m2.get("slc"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h3", m2.get("vs"));

    Map<String, String> m3 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    Assert.assertEquals("h2", m3.get("phx"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h3", m3.get("slc"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h0", m3.get("vs"));

    Map<String, String> m4 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    Assert.assertEquals("h3", m4.get("phx"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h0", m4.get("slc"));
    Assert.assertEquals("h1", m4.get("vs"));

    Map<String, String> m5 = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    Assert.assertNull(m5.get("phx"));
    Assert.assertNull(m5.get("slc"));
    Assert.assertNull(m5.get("vs"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed example. It works perfectly fine.. I have updated my question with one minor issue. Let me know if it is at all possible to implement here?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T, cool! The issue you are describing is the one I  have addressed between brackets `(may need to be adapted ...`, see my edit!

Comment: Thanks A4L. It works fine but as soon as it gets called sixth time - it gives me java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T change `if(hostListIndex == 0) {` to `if(hostListIndex <= 0) {` and it should work in an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. I know it's a pretty old post, but is there any way to avoid using while loop here? And instead of that have some sort of predefined combinations which I can know it beforehand? Currently while true will keep on running always and I want to avoid that.

Comment: You could generate all the combinations you need on startup and save them in a static list. There is no need for an endless loop as the combinations start repeting at some point. Define a static index and use it to rotate on the generated list when you need a new combonatin.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. How would I do that in this case? It should be part of `DatacenterMachineMapping` class?

Comment: Yes, you could do the generation in a static block and do the rotation in the getter mthod.

Comment: Can you provide an example on this basis on my example if possible.. I am trying it out on my end but it doesn't work for me somehow..

Comment: I'm afraid I can't :( ... I'm abroad and having only a tiny smartphone in my hand... So writing a piece of code is almost impossible :(... Anyways... Just replace the while(true) loop with a for loop going to numberOfHosts * numberOfDatacenters

Comment: Sure.. I can understand that.. For now I am having a for loop till `numberOfHosts`, if I do for loop till `numberOfHosts * numberOfDatacenters` then it will print out some empty strings..

Comment: This is the most you can go, but I think you dont have to since at each call you start assigning hosts at last index - 1,  just observe the while loop when the combinstin are stsrting to repeat and see how far you have to go.

Comment: @A4L: Are you back? I have solve the issue of while true which we discussed few weeks back but I am stuck on similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971988/find-the-combinations-given-n-number-of-box-with-x-number-of-balls). In this, number of balls is not same across all the boxes as we have in this current question.. I am using box and ball naming there just to make people understand better.. See if you can help me out there.. Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In order to know what combination you have generated previously, you need to store one number - the index of the initial host for the next combination. This index starts at zero, and is incremented in each call of `getDatacenterMachineMapping`. Hosts are assigned to centers in order, rotating back to index zero when the list of hosts is exhausted:

```
private static int nextAssignmentInitialIndex = 0;
private static Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {
    int i = nextAssignmentInitialIndex;
    Map<String, String> res = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (String h : hosts) {
        res.put(h, colo.get(i++));
        // If i has reached the end of the colo list, it rotates back to zero
        if (i == colo.size()) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    nextAssignmentInitialIndex = (nextAssignmentInitialIndex+1) % colo.size();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for the solution.. I am stuck on similar problem here. In this, number of balls is not same across all the boxes as we have in this current question.. I am using box and ball naming there just to make people understand better.. See if you can help me out there.. Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: @SSH If you have a question, please post it as a question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like below

```
private static List<String> colo = Arrays.asList("phx", "slc", "lvs");
private static List<String> hosts = Arrays.asList("h0","h1","h2", "h3");
private static AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
private static final int noOfHosts = 4;
while(true) {
    Map<String, String> coloHost = getDatacenterMachineMapping();
    System.out.println(coloHost);
}

private static Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {

int startIndex = index.getAndSet((index.inteValue()+1)%noOfHosts);
 Map<String, String> res = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (String h : hosts) {
        res.put(h, colo.get(startIndex++));
    }
    return res;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot saury. I tried your example and as soon as I run it, I always get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Any thoughts why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Here an implementation of circular permutations which is what you need to do : -

```
public class CircularPerm {

    public static void circularPerm(int i,int s,String[] set1,String[] set2) {

        if(i<set1.length) {

            if(i==0) {

               for(int k=0;k<set2.length;k++) {

                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println(set1[i]+": "+set2[k]);
                   circularPerm(i+1,(k+1)%(set2.length),set1,set2);

               }

            }

            else {
                    System.out.println(set1[i]+": "+set2[s]);
                    circularPerm(i+1,(s+1)%(set2.length), set1, set2);
            }

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] datacenters = {"phx", "slc", "lvs"};
        String[] machines = {"h0","h1","h2","h3"};
        circularPerm(0,0,datacenters,machines);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. I am stuck on similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971988/find-the-combinations-given-n-number-of-box-with-x-number-of-balls). In this, number of balls is not same across all the boxes as we have in this current question.. I am using box and ball naming there just to make people understand better.. See if you can help me out there.. Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks..