# Find the combinations, given n number of box with x number of balls

Tags: java, algorithm, list, dictionary, combinations

I am working on a project in which I have three box (as of now) and each box will have some color of balls

So I am storing them in a `Map of String and List of String` as shown below.

```
Map<String, List<String>> boxBallMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Data in the above map can be like this -

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[blue, red]}
{box3=[blue, red, orange]}
```

So possible combination of balls in the boxes can be -

**(POINT A)** :: All boxes having same number of balls -

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[blue, red, orange]}
{box3=[blue, red, orange]}

or
```

**(POINT B)** :: Any of the boxes doesn't have any balls. So let's say box3 doesn't have any balls -

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[blue, red, orange]}
{box3=[]}

or
```

**(POINT C)** :: Some boxes have less number of balls. So let's say box2 has only two balls -

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[blue, red]}
{box3=[blue, red, orange]}

or
```

**(POINT D)** :: Any of the boxes doesn't have any balls. So let's say box3 and box2 doesn't have any balls -

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[]}
{box3=[]}
```

**ProblemStatement:-**

Basis on the above input, I need to return a mapping which will be `List<Map<String, String>>`, let's say for **(POINT A)**, below mapping would be return as an output -

```
[{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}, 
{box1=red, box2=orange, box3=blue}, 
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}]
```

Here if you see, each row has alternate color of balls for each box -  meaning `blue for box1`, `red for box2`, `orange for box3`. I cannot have same color of balls in each row. So this combination is not possible as it has same color of balls for two boxes.

```
{box1=blue, box2=blue, box3=orange}
```

And also, in the second row, I won't use those balls which have been used in the first row for that box.

The output combination is getting generated basis on the input being passed as shown in **(POINT A)**.

Now, let's say for **(POINT B)** as an input in which `box3` doesn't have any balls, I will be returning another mapping as shown below which will be `List<Map<String, String>>` as well -

```
[{box1=blue, box2=red}, 
{box1=red, box2=orange}, 
{box1=orange, box2=blue}]
```

In the above output, you can see there is no `box3` as there was no input for it but box1 and box2 in each row has alternate colors of ball.

Now, let's say for **(POINT C)** as an input in which `box2` only has two color of balls, I will be returning another mapping as shown below which will be `List<Map<String, String>>` as well -

```
[{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}, 
{box1=red, box3=blue}, 
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}]
```

In the above output, you can see in the second row there is no `box2` as `box2` only has `red` and `blue` color of balls and to make the combination right, box2 is in first row and third row just to maintain the rule that each row will have alternate colors of ball.

Now I am not able to understand how would I write such method which can return me the mappings basis on the input I am passing for this problem?

**NOTE:-**

Here boxes will always be three for now but balls can vary as shown above in the input

Any suggestions will be of great help on this. Thanks.

**UPDATE:-**

My basic problem is given a input of balls and boxes as shown above - How would I return the mapping such that, in each row, boxes are using alternate/different color of balls and they need to make sure that in the previous row, those color of balls has not been used by the same box.

For **(POINT C)** as an input in which `box2` only has two color of balls, I would like to return mapping as shown below which will be `List<Map<String, String>>` as well -

```
[{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}, 
{box1=red, box3=blue}, 
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}]
```

- Here in first row, `box1 has blue`, `box2 has red`, `box3 has orange` which has alternate color of balls.
- In second row, `box1 has red` why? bcoz `blue` was already used in the first row for box1 and box3 has blue and no `box2` in second row.
- Similarly for third row as well.

Solution which I had earlier but this assume that number of balls is always same in each boxes -

```
public List<Map<String, String>> createMappings(List<String> boxes, List<String> balls) {
    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int j = 0; j < boxes.size(); j++) {
            String box = boxes.get(j);
            int ballIndex = (j + i) % balls.size();
            String ball = balls.get(ballIndex);
            row.put(box, ball);
        }
        result.add(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If we can modify this to start accepting my input as a Map and handle the use case when number of balls can be different, then it will become pretty easy for me

**UPDATE**

if I am trying on the below input combination, then I am getting output as empty which is wrong.

```
List<String> balls1 = Arrays.asList();
List<String> balls2 = Arrays.asList();
List<String> balls3 = Arrays.asList("red", "blue");


Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
maps.put("box3", balls3);
maps.put("box2", balls2);
maps.put("box1", balls1);

List<Map<String, String>> mappings = generateMappings(maps);

// below mappings is coming as empty somehow which is wrong
System.out.println(mappings);
```

But the output should come as below for the above input -

```
[{box3=red}, {box3=blue}]
```

And also, it doesn't work for the below input as well -

```
List<String> balls1 = Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "orange");
List<String> balls2 = Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "orange");
List<String> balls3 = Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "orange", "purple", "pink");
```

With the above input combination, I can see same color balls in the other rows for some boxes which violates third rule..

**UPDATE:-**

My rules are-

- In each row, boxes should have alternate colors of ball. If you see above, each row has alternate color of balls for each box -  meaning `blue for box1`, `red for box2`, `orange for box3` in first row.
- Secondly, I cannot have same color of balls in each row. So the below combination is not possible as it has same color of balls for two boxes in one row.
  `{box1=blue, box2=blue, box3=orange}`
- Thirdly, in the next row, I won't use those balls for the box which have been used in the earlier rows. So second row cannot have `blue` for `box1` as it was already used in first row by `box1`.

**Final Code:-**

SO final code should be like this -

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> create(Map<String, List<String>> input) {
List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
// find all boxes
List<String> boxes = new ArrayList<String>(input.keySet());

// find all colors
Set<String> distinctColors = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (List<String> e : input.values()) {
    for (String color : e) {
    if (!distinctColors.contains(color)) {
        distinctColors.add(color);
    }
    }
}
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(distinctColors);

Set<String> generationHistory = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
int colorIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
    Map<String, String> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    output.add(row);
    colorIndex = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < colors.size(); j++) {
    int boxIndex = j;
    if(boxIndex >= boxes.size()) {
        boxIndex = 0;
    }
    String box = boxes.get(boxIndex);
    List<String> boxColors = input.get(box);
    if(colorIndex >= colors.size()) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }
    String color = colors.get(colorIndex++);
    // a combination is generated only if the actual
    // colors does exist in the actual box 
    // and it has not already been generated i all previous rows
    if(boxColors.contains(color) && isNotYetGenerated(box, color, generationHistory)) {
        row.put(box, color);
    }
    }
}

return output;
}

private static boolean isNotYetGenerated(String box, String color, Set<String> generationHistory) {
String key = box + "=" + color;
boolean notYetGenerated = !generationHistory.contains(key);
if (notYetGenerated) {
    generationHistory.add(key);
}
return notYetGenerated;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can understand that.. :).. Think about it, the pain I went through while formatting the question.. :)

Comment: Can you clarify your basic problem? Are you asking how to return a list give input of colored balls for each box? Are you asking to evaluate the boxes and answer something (do all boxes have the same colors in them)? or ...?  Is this a question about how to list a "soduko" type of puzzle?  Start your explanation at a higher level: I need to return xxxx, given that I will have xx color balls that can go in yy boxes. ....

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: Sure. I have update my question with some details. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you just need to return all possible variants of reordering balls in the boxes to make each row contain balls of different color? If so, the simplest, though most naive way, would be to brute force all possible combinations, excluding ones that don't match.

Comment: @svz: yes that's what I need but one catch is number of balls can be different in each boxes such as `POINT B, POINT C, POINT D` in my question.

Comment: @SSH, The number of balls doesn't actually matter as well as the number of boxes. You take first ball from box1, then first ball from the next box. If it is of same color, go to ball two and so on. You can get the size of the current box easily. Go on while you have more boxes. Is it the algorithm or the implementation you have troubles with? P.S. Are you required to use maps to solve the problem?

Comment: I am having trouble in implementation with the use case when number of balls is different in each boxes..  I will edit the question with the solution I had but it is making assumption that number of balls is always same in each boxes. I am using Maps because it will be easy for me to iterate the output and the input is also in the Map as well so Map is my first choice..

Comment: What if box1, box2, and box3 each only have the red ball.  Would you expect 3 maps, box1=red, box2=red, box3=red?

Comment: @Pace:Yes. That is correct..

Comment: @Pace: Any idea how this can be done? I know you might be busy.. Whenever you are free, can you help?

Comment: This feels like [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Why is two times "red" in balls3? What is the expected output for that input? Can you summarise all the rules an put them all together in the question, its not easy to follow them based only on the examples. Can you apply those rules manually and get the desired output? Did you implement a `isNotYetGenerated()` method as suggested?

Comment: Sorry it was copy mistake.. It was pink.. May be I missed it, what is the purpose of `isNotYetGenerated()` method in general? Just updated question with the rules..

Comment: `isNotYetGenerated` - as its name suggests - should implement rule 3, i.e it should check whether a combination has already been generated in the previous row. Btw, how to exactly interpret 3rd rule? should the check be performed only for the previous row, i.e. **actual-1** or should it be performed for all previously generated **rows**?

Comment: That's a good point.. It should be performed for all previously generated rows.. if in row 1, box 1 has blue, in row 2, box 1 has red, then in row 3 box 1 cannot have blue or red, it should be orange. Hope that makes sense to you..

Comment: @A4L Any idea, what's wrong going on currently with the code?

Comment: @Al4L: I updated the question with the final code.. take a look and let me know -  that's what you were expecting as the final code?

Comment: @SSH Yes, from the first look I think it's the exact same code as the one I have. does it generate the right output for all your testcases (including the last one with purple and pink)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48511/discussion-between-ssh-and-a4l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you will have to combine all boxes with all possible colors. In each new row a box gets the next color assigned to that it had in the previous row. It becomes a bit clearer if you write all the possible box/color combinations and write all the indices. **PointA** is a perfect example:

For the input

```
{box1=[blue, red, orange]}
{box2=[blue, red, orange]}
{box3=[blue, red, orange]}
```

All combination for the above input are (with **boxIndex , colorIndex** in front):

```
0,0 {box1=blue}
0,1 {box1=red}
0,2 {box1=orange}

1,0 {box2=blue}
1,1 {box2=red}
1,2 {box2=orange}

2,0 {box3=blue}
2,1 {box3=red}
2,2 {box3=orange}
```

You are looking for the following output:

```
{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}
{box1=red, box2=orange, box3=blue}
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}
```

Thus the indices you are looking for are the following :

```
row1    0,0     1,1     2,2
row2    0,1     1,2     2,0
row3    0,2     1,0     2,1
```

Now when you know what you are looking for, it becomes easy to write some loops (**disclaimer: As far as I have correctly understood your question / Not fully tested!!!**):

```
public List<Map<String, String>> create(Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<>();
    // find all boxes
    List<String> boxes = new ArrayList<>(input.keySet());

    // find all colors
    Set<String> distinctColors = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(List<String> e : input.values()) {
        for(String color : e) {
            if(! distinctColors.contains(color)) {
                distinctColors.add(color);  
            }
        }
    }
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(distinctColors);

    int colorIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> row = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        output.add(row);
        colorIndex = i;
        for(int j = 0; j < colors.size(); j++) {
            int boxIndex = j;
            if(boxIndex >= boxes.size()) {
                boxIndex = 0;
            }
            String box = boxes.get(boxIndex);
            List<String> boxColors = input.get(box);
            if(colorIndex >= colors.size()) {
                colorIndex = 0;
            }
            String color = colors.get(colorIndex++);
            // a combination is generated only if the actual
            // colors does exist in the actual box
            if(boxColors.contains(color)) {
                row.put(box, color);    
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Here is some testings using some of the inputs you have provided:

**PointA**

```
@Test
public void createFromPointA() {
    //    {box1=[blue, red, orange]}
    //    {box2=[blue, red, orange]}
    //    {box3=[blue, red, orange]}

    //    [{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}, 
    //     {box1=red, box2=orange, box3=blue}, 
    //     {box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}]

    //    0,0 {box1=blue}
    //    0,1 {box1=red}
    //    0,2 {box1=orange}

    //    1,0 {box2=blue}
    //    1,1 {box2=red}
    //    1,2 {box2=orange}

    //    2,0 {box3=blue}
    //    2,1 {box3=red}
    //    2,2 {box3=orange}

    //    0,0   1,1     2,2
    //    0,1   1,2     2,0
    //    0,2   1,0     2,1

    Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));

    List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
    for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
        System.out.println(e);  
    }
}
```

**PointB**

```
@Test
public void createFromPointB() {
    //      {box1=[blue, red, orange]}
    //      {box2=[blue, red, orange]}
    //      {box3=[]}

    //      [{box1=blue, box2=red}, 
    //       {box1=red, box2=orange}, 
    //       {box1=orange, box2=blue}]

    //      0,0 {box1=blue}
    //      0,1 {box1=red}
    //      0,2 {box1=orange}

    //      1,0 {box2=blue}
    //      1,1 {box2=red}
    //      1,2 {box2=orange}

    //      2,x {box3=blue}
    //      2,x {box3=red}
    //      2,X {box3=orange}

    //      0,0     1,1     2,x
    //      0,1     1,1     2,x
    //      0,2     1,0     2,x

    Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box3", Collections.<String>emptyList());

    List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
    for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
        System.out.println(e);  
    }
}
```

**PointC**

```
@Test
public void createFromPointC() {
    //      {box1=[blue, red, orange]}
    //      {box2=[blue, red]}
    //      {box3=[blue, red, orange]}

    //      [{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}, 
    //       {box1=red, box3=blue}, 
    //       {box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}]

    //      0,0 {box1=blue}
    //      0,1 {box1=red}
    //      0,2 {box1=orange}

    //      1,0 {box2=blue}
    //      1,1 {box2=red}
    //      1,x {box2=orange}

    //      2,0 {box3=blue}
    //      2,1 {box3=red}
    //      2,2 {box3=orange}

    //      0,0     1,1     2,2
    //      0,1     1,x     2,0
    //      0,2     1,0     2,1

    Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("blue", "red"));
    input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("blue", "red", "orange"));

    List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
    for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
        System.out.println(e);  
    }
}
```

**OutputA**

```
{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}
{box1=red, box2=orange, box3=blue}
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}
```

**OutputB**

```
{box1=blue, box2=red}
{box1=red, box2=orange}
{box1=orange, box2=blue}
```

**OutputC**

```
{box1=blue, box2=red, box3=orange}
{box1=red, box3=blue}
{box1=orange, box2=blue, box3=red}
```

Hope this helps or at least give you some hints in your way finding a solution.

**EDIT**

You could replace the outer for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
```

This way the generation is oriented after the number of colors not that of the boxes. If this doesn't help with other combinations then you might want to add a check before adding a combination to a row:

```
if(boxColors.contains(color) && notYetGenerated()) {
    row.put(box, color);    
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a sample implementation of `isNotYetGenerated`

```
private boolean isNotYetGenerated(String box, String color, 
                                  Set<String> generationHistory) {
    String key = box + "=" + color;
    boolean notYetGenerated = ! generationHistory.contains(key);
    if(notYetGenerated) {
        generationHistory.add(key);
    }
    return notYetGenerated;
}
```

Create the set in the `create` method an pass it to that method.

```
    Set<String> generationHistory = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    int colorIndex = 0;
    int index = boxes.size() > colors.size() ?  boxes.size() : colors.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        Map<String, String> row = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        output.add(row);
        colorIndex = i;
        for(int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            int boxIndex = j;
            if(boxIndex >= boxes.size()) {
                boxIndex = 0;
            }
            String box = boxes.get(boxIndex);
            List<String> boxColors = input.get(box);
            if(colorIndex >= colors.size()) {
                colorIndex = 0;
            }
            String color = colors.get(colorIndex++);
            // a combination is generated only if the actual
            // colors does exist in the actual box 
            // and it has not already been generated i all previous rows
            if(boxColors.contains(color) && isNotYetGenerated(box, color, generationHistory)) {
                row.put(box, color);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Test for PonitF**

```
@Test
public void createFromPointF() {
    //      {box1=red, box2=blue, box3=orange}
    //      {box1=blue, box2=orange, box3=purple}
    //      {box1=red, box3=pink}
    //      {box3=red, box1=orange}
    //      {box3=blue}

    //      0,0    {box1=red}
    //      0,1    {box1=blue}
    //      0,2    {box1=orange}
    //      0,x    {box1=purple}
    //      0,x    {box1=pink}
    //
    //      1,0    {box2=red}
    //      1,1    {box2=blue}
    //      1,2    {box2=orange}
    //      1,x    {box2=purple}
    //      1,x    {box2=pink}
    //
    //      2,0    {box3=red}
    //      2,1    {box3=blue}
    //      2,2    {box3=orange}
    //      2,3    {box3=purple}
    //      2,4    {box3=pink}

    //      0,0     1,1     2,2
    //      0,1     1,2     2,3
    //      0,x     1,x     2,0
    //      0,x     1,0     2,1

    Map<String, List<String>> input = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    input.put("box1", Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "orange"));
    input.put("box2", Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "orange"));
    input.put("box3", Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "orange", "purple", "pink"));

    List<Map<String, String>> output = create(input);
    Assert.assertEquals(
            "{box1=red, box2=blue, box3=orange}\r\n" + 
            "{box1=blue, box2=orange, box3=purple}\r\n" + 
            "{box1=orange, box3=pink}\r\n" + 
            "{box3=red}\r\n" + 
            "{box2=red, box3=blue}\r\n", toString(output));
}

private String toString(List<Map<String, String>> output) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    for(Map<String, String> e : output) {
        sw.write(e.toString());
        sw.write("\r\n");
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

**OuputF**

```
{box1=red, box2=blue, box3=orange}
{box1=blue, box2=orange, box3=purple}
{box1=orange, box3=pink}
{box3=red}
{box2=red, box3=blue}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot A4L for the help.. I ran your example on my tests cases, everything works fine but one issue I noticed on one of my use case is if I have only two balls in box 1 and other boxes are empty.. I have updated the question for that issue..

Comment: Thanks A4L for the suggestion... That works but I see one more issue which I can fix it on my own I guess.. Appreciated your help..

Comment: While I was fixing some of the issues, I saw that on on some of the input combinations current code doesn't work properly.. I have updated the question with those input combinations.. See if you are able to find the problem in the code, otherwise I might need to spend more time in figuring out this.. I already spent couple of hours but not able to understand what is the problem in the code..

Comment: let me know whenever you are around.. Take a look at the chat session we were having..

Comment: @SSH, please see my reply in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48511/discussion-between-ssh-and-a4l)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following strategy (code not presented because this is "homework"):

1. Create a `Ball` class that has color
2. Create a `Box` class that has a count method for the number of balls, and an addBall method
3. Create a "choose" method in Box that you give an Array of balls and it will pull a ball out of hte box that does NOT match any of the colors on the ball array input or null.

Start working on your output by creating columns (with a size of the max number of balls in a box), then for row 1 pull a ball from box 1 that does not have a ball color from previously pulled balls)
for row 2 pull a ball from box 2 that does not have a color in the column)
...

Comment: It's not an homework. I have provided the code in the question but it assumes number of balls is same in all the boxes. I didn't provided earlier because the question was getting pretty long so avoided it earlier. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, what you could do is the following:

1. sort the boxes by the number of balls they have in it (ascending, from the smallest to the largest box).
2. while there are colors left
3. loop over the sorted list of boxes
4. in each iteration pick a color from the box (if there is one left), that is not already picked in the current iteration (of the while loop)

Hope this helps. No code, have to sleep.

EDIT: here is the pseudocode:

```
arranged_colors = [] // empty list, this is you desired output
sort_the_boxes(boxes) // ascending, by the number of colors in it
while( there_are_more_colors_left() ) { // a method that is easy to implement
  current_list = [] // empty list
  for( box in boxes ) {
    for( color in box ) {
      if( not color in current_list ) {
        current_list.add(color)
        box.remove(color)
        break
      }
    }
  }
  aranged_colors.add(current_colors)
}
```

Comment: Thanks You.. I am stuck on the implementation part somehow.. Logic wise I was on the same track as you pointed out but somehow not able to make that work.. Whatever code I have (shown in question) as of now only works with number of balls same in each boxes..

Comment: Thanks B.J. I tried implementing your algo but didn't able to complete that as I am not able to understand how would I do few things so I am stuck on this from so long.. if you can provide an example then it will be of great help to me.. Thanks for the help.