# How to validate a String whether it is in YYYYMMDD format?

Tags: java, string, date

I have a string which is being passed to one of my method in the form of `YYYYMMDD` -

```
public static void verifyInput(String input) {    


}
```

Here input passed will be in this form "YYYYMMDD";

How do I validate whether `input` String which is passed in this form `YYYYMMDD` only?

I just need to validate whether it is in `YYYYMMDD` this format.. I don't need to get the current date in this `YYYYMMDD` format and then compare it with `ss`.

**UPDATE:-**

I just need to validate the string input to see whether they are in this format `YYYYMMDD`

Meaning if anyone is passing a String `hello` then it is not in this `YYYYMMDD` format..

And if anyone is passing this String `20130130` then this gets validated as it is in this `YYYYMMDD` format..

Comment: Run it through `SimpleDateFormat` with `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: input.matches("\\d{8}") tests if input consists of 8 digits.

Comment: Validating that year and month are in bounds is easy, but validating that day of month is consistent with the month (and year, for leap year) is much harder.  Using a date converter makes sense if you need full validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), here is one solution -

```
private static final java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

public static java.util.Date verifyInput(String input) {
  if (input != null) {
    try {
      java.util.Date ret = sdf.parse(input.trim());
      if (sdf.format(ret).equals(input.trim())) {
        return ret;
      }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] dates = new String[] { "20141031",
      "20130228", "20000229", "20000230" };
  for (String str : dates) {
    System.out.println(verifyInput(str));
  }
}
```

Outputs

```
Fri Oct 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014
Thu Feb 28 00:00:00 EST 2013
Tue Feb 29 00:00:00 EST 2000
null
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott.. Makes sense now.. I was not aware of `SimpleDateFormat`... Learned something new today.... I am stuck on one more problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971988/find-the-combinations-given-n-number-of-box-with-x-number-of-balls). See if you can help me out there.. Thanks for the help..

Comment: You need to set lenient false (setLenient(false);) for simple date format otherwise sometimes results will be invalid for example yyyy-mm-dd will get parse with wrong date.

Comment: The answer is correct. For new readers to this question and/or this answer I recommend that we don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDmm").parse(input);
    // good format
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // bad format
}
```

Comment: +1. Simple Enough... Thanks B.J... Makes sense now.. I am stuck on one more problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971988/find-the-combinations-given-n-number-of-box-with-x-number-of-balls). See if you can help me out there.. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1):

Using RegExp ([Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) & [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)):

```
public static void verifyInput(String input) {    
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\d{4}(1[012]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12]\d|0[0-9])$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
```

(While it does check for valid month and day nubmers, it doesn't check if the current month only has 28/30 days. thatn can be added though if you need to check it.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
private boolean validateDateFormat(String input) {
    if(input == null) {
        return false;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        Date d = format.parse(input);
        logger.debug(d);
        return true;
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unit testing it with this method:

```
@Test
public void TestDateValidation() {
    logger.info("\ntestDateValidation()");

    assertEquals(false, validateDateFormat("hello"));
    assertEquals(false, validateDateFormat(null));
    assertEquals(false, validateDateFormat(""));
    assertEquals(false, validateDateFormat("d20140228"));
    assertEquals(false, validateDateFormat("Feb 28, 2014"));

    assertEquals(true, validateDateFormat("20140228"));
    validateDateFormat("20140229");
    validateDateFormat("2014024000");

}
```

gives this output:

```
Fri Feb 28 00:00:00 EST 2014
Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 EST 2014
Mon Jan 13 00:00:00 EST 2025
```

Unfortunately, those two wacky dates are still parsed as if they were real dates, but it looks like that is not a problem based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_PARSER
        = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ERA, IsoEra.CE.getValue())
                .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

/** @throws DateTimeParseException if the input date is invalid */
public static void verifyInput(String input) {    
    LocalDate.parse(input, DATE_PARSER);
}
```

Trying it out:

```
    String[] sampleStrings = { "20211231", "00000714",
            "20200229", "20210229", "9990731", "100000714" };
    for (String sample : sampleStrings) {
        try {
            verifyInput(sample);
            System.out.println("Valid:   " + sample);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println("Invalid: " + sample);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> Valid:   20211231
> Invalid: 00000714
> Valid:   20200229
> Invalid: 20210229
> Invalid: 9990731
> Invalid: 100000714
> ```

I am using `yyyy` in the format pattern to make sure that the year is strictly positive (at least 0001). I’m using `ResolverStyle.STRICT` to rule out February 29 in non-leap years, for example. And to make that work I need to supply an era since otherwise every year would be ambiguous and Java would refuse to resolve it strictly. CE s the common era, “Anno Domini”.

### In the code it’s `yyyyMMdd` (not `YYYYMMDD`)

I understood YYYYMMDD as 4-digit year, 2-digit month and 2-digit day of month the way most English-speaking users without any special knowledge of programming will understand it. In Java and other programming languages the format pattern letters are case sensitive. Some of them are:

| Symbol | Meaning and comment |
| --- | --- |
| y | year-of-era; from 1 |
| Y | week-based-year; only useful with a week number |
| u | year; a signed year as used in the proleptic Gregorian calendar and in ISO 8601; allows 0 (introduced with java.time, did not work with the old `SimpleDateFormat`) |
| M | month-of-year |
| m | minute-of-hour |
| d | day-of-month; 0 through 28–31 |
| D | day-of-year; 0 through 365 or 366 |

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Pass it into a SImpleDateFormat object for format string yyyyMMdd.

Answer (score 0):

you can validate it through..

```
boolean validate(String s)
{
     if(s.length()!=8)
     return false;
     try{
          int year=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,4));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          return false;
     }
     try{
          int month=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(4,6));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          return false;
     }
     try{
          int date=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6,8));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          return false;
     }
     if(month>12)
     return false;
     if(date>31)
     return false;
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: You should also check month < 1 and date < 1.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Neuron's answer:

```
 if (month < 1 || month > 12)
     return false;
 int days = 30;
 if (month == 2) {
     days = 28;
     if ((year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))) days = 29;
 }
 else {
     if ((1 << month) & 0x15A2) days = 31;
 }
 if (date < 1 || date > days)
     return false;
 return true;
```

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks for the suggestion... It is slightly different than other approach but does the work.. I am stuck on one more problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971988/find-the-combinations-given-n-number-of-box-with-x-number-of-balls). See if you can help me out there.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Validate using *Apache [commons-validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.7)*

```
GenericValidator.isDate("20130130", "yyyyMMdd", true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert String to Date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");
Date date = sdf.parse(input);
```

Comment: You might want to study [this document](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Pattern `YYYYMMDD` does not work. You may want to see the explanation in my answer.